# Using ModuleDict, I have: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying in my `__init__` function:

```
        self.downscale_time_conv = np.empty(8, dtype=object)
        for i in range(8):
            self.downscale_time_conv[i] = torch.nn.ModuleDict({})
```

But in my `forward`, I have:

```
        down_out = False
        for i in range(8):
            if not down_out:
                down_out = self.downscale_time_conv[i][side](inputs)
            else:
                down_out += self.downscale_time_conv[i][side](inputs)
```

and I get:

```
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013109/runtimeerror-input-type-torch-floattensor-and-weight-type-torch-cuda-floatte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        self.downscale_time_conv = torch.nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(8):
            self.downscale_time_conv.append(torch.nn.ModuleDict({}))
```

this solved it. Apparently I needed to use a `ModuleList`