# Research Question (Help): RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, gpu

No idea what's happening in my case:

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_parametric_pytorch.py", line 127, in <module>
    ops = opfun(X_train[smpl])
  File "plot_parametric_pytorch.py", line 81, in <lambda>
    opfun = lambda X: model.forward(Variable(torch.from_numpy(X)))
  File "/mnt_home/klee/LBSBGenGapSharpnessResearch/vgg.py", line 43, in forward
    x = self.features(x).to(device)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 100, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 349, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 346, in _conv_forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

Source code:

```
[import statements]
cudnn.benchmark = True
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_train = np.transpose(X_train, axes=(0, 3, 1, 2))
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_test = np.transpose(X_test, axes=(0, 3, 1, 2))
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255
device = torch.device('cuda:0')

# This is where you can load any model of your choice.
# I stole PyTorch Vision's VGG network and modified it to work on CIFAR-10.
# You can take this line out and add any other network and the code
# should run just fine.
model = vgg.vgg11_bn()
model.to(device)


# Forward pass
opfun = lambda X: model.forward(Variable(torch.from_numpy(X))) <------

# Forward pass through the network given the input
predsfun = lambda op: np.argmax(op.data.numpy(), 1)

# Do the forward pass, then compute the accuracy
accfun = lambda op, y: np.mean(np.equal(predsfun(op), y.squeeze()))*100

# Initial point
x0 = deepcopy(model.state_dict())

# Number of epochs to train for
# Choose a large value since LB training needs higher values
# Changed from 150 to 30
nb_epochs = 30
batch_range = [25, 40, 50, 64, 80, 128, 256, 512, 625, 1024, 1250, 1750, 2048, 2500, 3125, 4096, 5000]

# parametric plot (i.e., don't train the network)
hotstart = False

if not hotstart:
    for batch_size in batch_range:
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
        model.load_state_dict(x0)
        model.to(device)
        average_loss_over_epoch = '-'
        print('Optimizing the network with batch size %d' % batch_size)
        np.random.seed(1337) #So that both networks see same sequence of batches
        for e in range(nb_epochs):
            model.eval()
            print('Epoch:', e, ' of ', nb_epochs, 'Average loss:', average_loss_over_epoch)
            average_loss_over_epoch = 0
            # Checkpoint the model every epoch
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), "./models/30EpochC3ExperimentBatchSize" + str(batch_size) + ".pth")
            array = np.random.permutation(range(X_train.shape[0]))
            slices = X_train.shape[0] // batch_size
            beginning = 0
            end = 1

            # Training loop!
            for _ in range(slices):
                start_index = batch_size * beginning 
                end_index = batch_size * end
                smpl = array[start_index:end_index]
                model.train()
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                ops = opfun(X_train[smpl]) <-----
                tgts = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_train[smpl]).long().squeeze())
                loss_fn = F.nll_loss(ops, tgts)
                average_loss_over_epoch += loss_fn.data.numpy() / fractions_of_dataset
                loss_fn.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                beginning += 1
                end += 1
```

And here is where the model is constructed (and the forward method) [vgg.py]

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
F = nn.functional
import torch.utils.model_zoo as model_zoo
import math


__all__ = [
    'VGG', 'vgg11', 'vgg11_bn', 'vgg13', 'vgg13_bn', 'vgg16', 'vgg16_bn',
    'vgg19_bn', 'vgg19',
]


model_urls = {
    'vgg11': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/pytorch/models/vgg11-fb7e83b2.pth',
    'vgg13': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/pytorch/models/vgg13-58758d87.pth',
    'vgg16': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/pytorch/models/vgg16-82412952.pth',
    'vgg19': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/pytorch/models/vgg19-341d7465.pth',
}


class VGG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features):
        super(VGG, self).__init__()
        self.features = features.cuda()
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(512, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(4096, 10),
        )
        self._initialize_weights()

    def forward(self, x):
        device = torch.device('cuda:0')
        x.cuda()
        x.to(device)
        x = self.features(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x)
```

My full source code is here https://github.com/kristyelee/LBSBGenGapSharpnessResearch/blob/master/plot_parametric_pytorch.py
https://github.com/kristyelee/LBSBGenGapSharpnessResearch/blob/master/vgg.py

I read this for some information, [RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013109/runtimeerror-input-type-torch-floattensor-and-weight-type-torch-cuda-floatte) but I'm not sure how to put the input tensors on the GPU.. I kind of tried to do this with x.cuda() not sure if this is right or not though. I really want to put my model on the GPU to train faster (because I'm currently just using the CPU otherwise, which is *slow*)