# Convolutional Autoencoder CIFAR10 PyTorch - RuntimeError

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I am using PyTorch version: 1.9.0+cu102 with Convolutional Autoencoder for CIFAR-10 dataset as follows:

```
# Define transformations for training and test sets-
transform_train = transforms.Compose(
    [
      # transforms.RandomCrop(32, padding = 4),
      # transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
      transforms.ToTensor(),
      # transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010)),
     ]
     )

transform_test = transforms.Compose(
    [
      transforms.ToTensor(),
      # transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010)),
     ]
     )

# Load dataset-
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(
        root = './data', train = True,
        download = True, transform = transform_train
        )

test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(
        root = './data', train = False,
        download = True, transform = transform_test
        )

print(f"len(train_dataset) = {len(train_dataset)} & len(test_dataset) = {len(test_dataset)}")
# len(train_dataset) = 50000 & len(test_dataset) = 10000


batch_size = 64

# Create training and testing loaders-
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset, batch_size = batch_size,
        shuffle = True
        )

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        test_dataset, batch_size = batch_size,
        shuffle = False
        )

print(f"len(train_loader) = {len(train_loader)} & len(test_loader) = {len(test_loader)}")
# len(train_loader) = 782 & len(test_loader) = 157

# Sanity check-
len(train_dataset) / batch_size, len(test_dataset) / batch_size
# (781.25, 156.25)

# Get some random training images-
images, labels = next(iter(train_loader))
print(f"images.shape: {images.shape} & labels.shape: {labels.shape}")
# images.shape: torch.Size([64, 3, 32, 32]) & labels.shape: torch.Size([64])

LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
num_epochs = 20


class Reshape(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape = args
    
    def forward(self, x):
        return x.view(self.shape)


class Trim(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        return x[:, :, :32, :32]
        
encoder = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(
        in_channels = 3, out_channels = 32,
        kernel_size = 3, padding = 1,
        stride = 1, bias = True
        ),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope = 0.01),
     
    nn.Conv2d(
        in_channels = 32, out_channels = 64,
        kernel_size = 3, padding = 1,
        stride = 2, bias = True
        ),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope = 0.01),
    
    nn.Conv2d(
        in_channels = 64, out_channels = 64,
        kernel_size = 3, padding = 1,
        stride = 2, bias = True
        ),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope = 0.01),
    
    nn.Conv2d(
        in_channels = 64, out_channels = 64,
        kernel_size = 3, padding = 1,
        stride = 1, bias = True
        ),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope = 0.01),

    nn.Flatten(),
    
    nn.Linear(
        in_features = 4096, out_features = 1500,
        bias = True
    ),
    nn.Linear(
        in_features = 1500, out_features = 500,
        bias = True
    ),
    nn.Linear(
        in_features = 500, out_features = 100,
        bias = True
    )
)

# Sanity check-
x = torch.rand(size = (32, 3, 32, 32))
print(f"x.shape = {x.shape}")

encoder_op = encoder(x)
print(f"encoder_op.shape = {encoder_op.shape}")
# x.shape = torch.Size([32, 3, 32, 32])
# encoder_op.shape = torch.Size([32, 100])

decoder = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(
        in_features = 100, out_features = 500,
        bias = True),
    nn.Linear(
        in_features = 500, out_features = 1500,
        bias = True),
    nn.Linear(
        in_features = 1500, out_features = 4096,
        bias = True),
    
    Reshape(-1, 64, 8, 8),
    
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(
        in_channels = 64, out_channels = 64,
        kernel_size = 3, stride = 1,
        padding = 1, bias = True),
    # output: torch.Size([32, 64, 8, 8])
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(
        in_channels = 64, out_channels = 64,
        kernel_size = 3, stride = 2,
        padding = 1, bias = True),
    # output: torch.Size([32, 64, 15, 15])
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(
        in_channels = 64, out_channels = 32,
        kernel_size = 3, stride = 2,
        padding = 0, bias = True),
    # torch.Size([32, 32, 31, 31])
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(
        in_channels = 32, out_channels = 3,
        kernel_size = 3, stride = 1,
        padding = 0, bias = True),
    # output: torch.Size([32, 3, 33, 33])
    
    Trim(),
    # (3, 33, 33) -> (3, 32, 32)
    nn.Sigmoid()
    
)

# Sanity check-
decoder(encoder_op).shape
# torch.Size([32, 3, 32, 32])


class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x

# Initialize an autoencoder instance-
model = AutoEncoder()

# Move model to (GPU) device-
model.to(device)

# Specify optimizer and loss function-
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)
loss_fn = F.mse_loss

num_epochs = 15

# Python3 lists to hold training metrics-
trainining_loss = []
validation_loss = []

def compute_epoch_loss_autoencoder(model, data_loader, loss_fn, device):
    model.eval()
    curr_loss, num_examples = 0., 0
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        for features, _ in data_loader:
            features = features.to(device)
            logits = model(features)
            loss = loss_fn(logits, features, reduction='sum')
            num_examples += features.size(0)
            curr_loss += loss

        curr_loss = curr_loss / num_examples
        return curr_loss

start_time = time.time()

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    running_loss = 0.0

    model.train()
    
    for batch_idx, (features, _) in enumerate(train_loader):
        
        features = features.to(device)
        
        # forward and back prop-
        logits = model(features)  # make predictions using model
        loss = loss_fn(logits, features)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # Perform backprop-
        loss.backward()
        
        # Update model parameters-
        optimizer.step()
        
        # Compute model's performance-
        running_loss += loss.item() * features.size(0)
    
    # Compute loss using training dataset-
    epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_dataset)
    trainining_loss.append(epoch_loss)

    # Compute loss using validation dataset-
    val_loss = compute_epoch_loss_autoencoder(
        model, test_loader,
        loss_fn, device
        )
    validation_loss.append(val_loss)

    print(f"Epoch = {epoch + 1}: Autoencoder train loss = {epoch_loss:.4f} & val loss = {val_loss:.4f}")


end_time = time.time()

# Get some validation images-
for img, label in test_loader:
    break

img.shape, label.shape
# (torch.Size([64, 3, 32, 32]), torch.Size([64]))

img.to(device)

# Pass batch size = 64 images through encoder to get latent space representations-
model.encoder(img)
```

This line gives me the error:

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>
> in ()
> ----> 1 model.encoder(img)
>
> 4 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in
> _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
> 438                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
> 439         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
> --> 440                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
> 441
> 442     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
>
> RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type
> (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same or input should be a MKLDNN tensor and weight is a dense tensor

What's going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013109/runtimeerror-input-type-torch-floattensor-and-weight-type-torch-cuda-floatte)

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to the question. If the suggested target solves your problem, then you can accept it as a duplicate.