# Error: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to train a DNN model using pytorch, and I want to use GPU to train my model. I am able to successfully copy my model to the GPU using `model.to(device)`, where `device = cuda:0`.

However, the standard methods for copying input to the GPU, ([RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59013109)), that is, `X.to(device)` and `X.cuda()` does not give me the desired output. Following is the method I am currently implementing:

```
def train_loop(self, dataloader, device):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        # Compute prediction and loss
        print(device)
        X.to(device)
        print(X.is_cuda)
        y.to(device)
        
        pred = self.model(X)
        loss = self.loss_fn(pred, y)
```

On printing the device value `print(device)` it shows as: `cuda:0`. But when I run `print(X.is_cuda)` it returns `false`. (Screenshot attached below).

[image: Error Message]

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X.to(device)` does nothing.
change it to:

```py
x=x.to(device)
```

Of course this should be done to any parameter\variable you want on the GPU

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you! This resolved the problem