# RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.DoubleTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am training a CNN to classify some images. The objective is to classify them into two classes. I already executed the same code on Windows with a RTX3070, now I am trying to do the exact same on Ubuntu with a Nvidea A100-40Gb. The code I am using is this one:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
%matplotlib inline

import os

from sklearn.calibration import calibration_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools

import torch
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.optim import lr_scheduler

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    print("CUDA available. Using GPU acceleration.")
    device = "cuda"
else:
    print("CUDA is NOT available. Using CPU for training.")
    device = "cpu"

import pickle

def save_var(var,filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(var, f)

def recover_var(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        var = pickle.load(f)    
    return var

    
df = recover_var('dataframe_cnn.pickle') #my dataset
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

df.columns = ['label'] + list(range(1,27649))

train =df[:int(0.7*len(df))]
test = df[int(0.7*len(df)):]

def preprocessing(train, test, split_train_size = 0.2):
    
    # Split data into features(pixels) and labels(numbers from 0 to 9)
    targets = train.label.values
    features = train.drop(["label"], axis = 1).values
    
    # Normalization
    features = features/255.
    X_test = test.values/255.
    
    # Train test split. Size of train data is (1-split_train_size)*100% and size of test data is split_train_size%. 
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(features,
                                                      targets,
                                                      test_size = split_train_size,
                                                      random_state = 42) 
    
    # Create feature and targets tensor for train set. I need variable to accumulate gradients. Therefore first I create tensor, then I will create variable
    X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train)
    y_train = torch.from_numpy(y_train).type(torch.LongTensor) # data type is long

    # Create feature and targets tensor for test set.
    X_val = torch.from_numpy(X_val)
    y_val = torch.from_numpy(y_val).type(torch.LongTensor) # data type is long
    
    # Create feature tensor for train set.
    X_test = torch.from_numpy(X_test)
    
    return X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test

X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test = preprocessing(train, test)

print(f'Shape of training data: {X_train.shape}')
print(f'Shape training labels: {y_train.shape}')
print(f'Shape of validation data: {X_val.shape}')
print(f'Shape of valiation labels: {y_val.shape}')
print(f'Shape of testing data: {X_test.shape}')

# batch_size, epoch and iteration
BATCH_SIZE = 100
N_ITER = 2500
EPOCHS = 5
# I will be trainin the model on another 10 epochs to show flexibility of pytorch
EXTRA_EPOCHS = 10

# Pytorch train and test sets
train_tensor = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
val_tensor = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_val, y_val)
test_tensor = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_test)

# data loader
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_tensor, 
                                           batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                           shuffle = True)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_tensor, 
                                         batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                                         shuffle = False)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_tensor, 
                                          batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                          shuffle = False)



class CNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
        
        # convolution 1
        self.c1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(5,5), stride=1, padding=0)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        
        # maxpool 1
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2))
        
        # dropout 1
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        
        # convolution 2
        self.c2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1, padding=0)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        
        # maxpool 2
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2))

        # dropout 2
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        
        # linear 1
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32*5*5, 256)
        
        # dropout 3
        self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        
        # linear 2
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 10)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        
        out = self.c1(x) # [BATCH_SIZE, 16, 24, 24]
        out = self.relu1(out) 
        out = self.maxpool1(out) # [BATCH_SIZE, 16, 12, 12]
        out = self.dropout1(out) 
        
        out = self.c2(out) # [BATCH_SIZE, 32, 10, 10]
        out = self.relu2(out) 
        out = self.maxpool2(out) # [BATCH_SIZE, 32, 5, 5]
        out = self.dropout2(out) 
        
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1) # [BATCH_SIZE, 32*5*5=800]
        out = self.fc1(out) # [BATCH_SIZE, 256]
        out = self.dropout3(out)
        out = self.fc2(out) # [BATCH_SIZE, 10]
        
        return out
    
    
# Create CNN
model = CNNModel()

# Optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.003)

# Cross Entropy Loss 
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# LR scheduler
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=3, gamma=0.5)

# On GPU if possible
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    print("Model will be training on GPU")
    model = model.cuda()
    criterion = criterion.cuda()
else:
    print("Model will be training on CPU")


def fit(epoch):
    
    print("Training...")
    # Set model on training mode
    model.train()
    
    # Update lr parameter
    exp_lr_scheduler.step()
    
    # Initialize train loss and train accuracy
    train_running_loss = 0.0
    train_running_correct = 0
    train_running_lr = optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']
    
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data, target = Variable(data.view(BATCH_SIZE,1,144,192)), Variable(target)
        
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            data = data.cuda()
            target = target.cuda()
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        
        train_running_loss += loss.item()
        _, preds = torch.max(output.data, 1)
        train_running_correct += (preds == target).sum().item()
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        if (batch_idx + 1)% 50 == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                 epoch+1, 
                 (batch_idx + 1) * len(data), 
                 len(train_loader.dataset),
                 BATCH_SIZE * (batch_idx + 1) / len(train_loader), 
                 loss.cpu().detach().numpy())
                 )
            
    train_loss = train_running_loss/len(train_loader.dataset)
    train_accuracy = 100. * train_running_correct/len(train_loader.dataset)    
    
    return train_loss, train_accuracy, train_running_lr


def validate(data_loader):
    
    print("Validating...")
    # Set model on validating mode
    model.eval()
    val_preds = torch.LongTensor().cuda()
    val_proba = torch.LongTensor().cuda()
    
    # Initialize validation loss and validation accuracy
    val_running_loss = 0.0
    val_running_correct = 0
    
    for data, target in data_loader:
        # Regarding volatile argument, check the note below
        data, target = Variable(data.view(BATCH_SIZE,1,144,192), volatile=True), Variable(target)
        
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            data = data.cuda()
            target = target.cuda()
        
        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        
        val_running_loss += loss.item()
        pred = output.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
        proba = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output.data)

        val_running_correct += pred.eq(target.data.view_as(pred)).cpu().sum() 
        
        # Store val_predictions with probas for confusion matrix calculations & best errors made
        val_preds = torch.cat((val_preds.float(), pred), dim=0).float()
        val_proba = torch.cat((val_proba.float(), proba)).float()

    val_loss = val_running_loss/len(data_loader.dataset)
    val_accuracy = 100. * val_running_correct/len(data_loader.dataset) 
    
    return val_loss, val_accuracy, val_preds, val_proba

train_loss, train_accuracy = [], []
val_loss, val_accuracy = [], []
val_preds, val_proba = [], []
train_lr = []

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1} of {EPOCHS}\n")
    
    train_epoch_loss, train_epoch_accuracy, train_epoch_lr = fit(epoch)
    val_epoch_loss, val_epoch_accuracy, val_epoch_preds, val_epoch_proba = validate(val_loader)
    
    train_loss.append(train_epoch_loss)
    train_accuracy.append(train_epoch_accuracy)
    train_lr.append(train_epoch_lr)
    
    val_loss.append(val_epoch_loss)
    val_accuracy.append(val_epoch_accuracy)
    val_preds.append(val_epoch_preds)
    val_proba.append(val_epoch_proba)
    
    print(f"Train Loss: {train_epoch_loss:.4f}, Train Acc: {train_epoch_accuracy:.2f}")
    print(f'Val Loss: {val_epoch_loss:.4f}, Val Acc: {val_epoch_accuracy:.2f}\n')
```

However, it is returning the following error:

````
Cell In[149], line 285
    281 for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    283     print(f"Epoch {epoch+1} of {EPOCHS}\n")
--> 285     train_epoch_loss, train_epoch_accuracy, train_epoch_lr = fit(epoch)
    286     val_epoch_loss, val_epoch_accuracy, val_epoch_preds, val_epoch_proba = validate(val_loader)
    288     train_loss.append(train_epoch_loss)

Cell In[149], line 213, in fit(epoch)
    210     target = target.cuda()
    212 optimizer.zero_grad()
--> 213 output = model(data)
    214 loss = criterion(output, target)
    216 train_running_loss += loss.item()

File /opt/miniconda3/envs/mlgpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1130, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1126 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1127 # this function, and just call forward.
   1128 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Cell In[149], line 152, in CNNModel.forward(self, x)
    150 def forward(self, x):
--> 152     out = self.c1(x) # [BATCH_SIZE, 16, 24, 24]
    153     out = self.relu1(out) 
    154     out = self.maxpool1(out) # [BATCH_SIZE, 16, 12, 12]

File /opt/miniconda3/envs/mlgpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1130, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1126 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1127 # this function, and just call forward.
   1128 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /opt/miniconda3/envs/mlgpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py:457, in Conv2d.forward(self, input)
    456 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 457     return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)

File /opt/miniconda3/envs/mlgpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py:453, in Conv2d._conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    449 if self.padding_mode != 'zeros':
    450     return F.conv2d(F.pad(input, self._reversed_padding_repeated_twice, mode=self.padding_mode),
    451                     weight, bias, self.stride,
    452                     _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 453 return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
    454                 self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)

RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.DoubleTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same```
````

I already tried to typecast the output to float, torch.float, np.float32, but it still returned the same error. Moreover, I tried to change the type of the variable `x` on line 152, without results. How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013109/runtimeerror-input-type-torch-floattensor-and-weight-type-torch-cuda-floatte ? Could be a device mismatch (between input and model) issue

Comment: How do you load X_train?

Comment: @lukess I updated to shown the entire code.

Comment: @donut have you tried X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train).type(torch.FloatTensor) and X_val = torch.from_numpy(X_val).type(torch.FloatTensor)? or X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train.astype(np.float32))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your model parameters are in `Float` but your data is in `Double` datatype. I'm not sure exactly how you attempted to cast your tensor but the following should work:

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
output = model(data.float())
```

Alternatively, you can convert the model parameters to `Double` by the following:

```
# Create CNN
model = CNNModel()
model.double()
```

Try either of them and it should tackle the tensor type mismatch issue.

**NOTE:** Do not use `Variable(tensor)` as you did in the following:

```
for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    data, target = Variable(data.view(BATCH_SIZE,1,144,192)), Variable(target)
```

as well as here:

```
for data, target in data_loader:
    # Regarding volatile argument, check the note below
    data, target = Variable(data.view(BATCH_SIZE,1,144,192), volatile=True), Variable(target)
```

The [Variable API](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated) has been deprecated by PyTorch.

Comment: When I do any of the changes you suggested, it returns me an error on line ```out = self.fc1(out)```: ```RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (100x50048 and 800x256)
```

Comment: That's actually another issue. You are getting the shape mismatch because you are hardcoding the input channel here: `# linear 1
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32*5*5, 256)`. Your `fc1` layer would only take data with dimension `800x256` while your data after `out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)` is having a different dimension.

Comment: You can either hardcode that dimension as the `in_channel` in `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_channel, 256)` or add a adaptive pooling layer in your `forward` function which would take care of the spatial dimension. You can do that by `out = F.adaptive_avg_pool2d(out, 1)` and then `out = out.view(-1, 256)` in your `forward` function. Also change the `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32*5*5, 256)` to `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 256)`.

Comment: Changing the ```forward``` function as you instructed caused this error: ```RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 256]' is invalid for input of size 3200```

Comment: Assuming that your inputs have the dimension of `[100, 1, 144, 192] = [N, C, H, W]`, change this `out = out.view(-1, 256)` to `out = out.view(-1, out.shape[1])` in your `forward` function. Then change this `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 256)` to `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32, 256)` in your `__init__` function. This should work now.

Comment: Thank you, the combination of all you have said worked.